# How to enable PHP APC in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

i am new at `ubuntu` and i am moving from `windows`, i am starting to make `PHP` sites and one of them requires me to enable `APC`, the site uses a `PHP Framework` called `YII` and whenever i visit it throws an error: `CApcCache requires PHP apc extension to be loaded.`, i have searched over the internet about how to enable it and all i found is to edit this file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and change this line

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1 //default was 0 and i changed it to 1
```

then to run this command in terminal

```
sudo php5enmod opcache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but the site still throws the same error, isn't this the way to enable `APC` anymore?

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pecl install apc`?

Answer (score 0):

> isn't this the way to enable `APC` anymore?

No. In fact, this has *never* been the way to enable APC. What you did there was enabling the [opcache](http://php.net/manual/book.opcache.php) module. Having said that, I believe modifying the `php.ini` has been bogus as `php5enmod opcache` should have made all necessary modification needed to enable said module.

APC and opcache have in common that they both serve as opcode caches (a.k.a. bytecode accelerators). In addition, APC features a usercache part, which is what [CApcCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApcCache) is using. Now as of PHP 5.5, APC became obsolete (you can still compile a version from the repository, though. I do know it works on 5.5 but can't really recommend it) and opcache took its place in form of a core module (as opposed to APC being a pecl extension). It bears mentioning that APC and opcache cannot be enabled at the same time.

As mentioned before, APC exposes a usercache part. This is a feature that you will find missing in opcache. To make up for that, there's [APCu](http://php.net/manual/book.apcu.php) which is APC with its opcode cache part stripped. As APCu is meant to be a drop-in replacement for APC, `CApcCache` should be able to make use of it. Recently new versions of Yii even adress APCu directly.